# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 when Bundle Install

Tags: ruby, homebrew, mysql-connector

Not really understanding what's going on. I just wanted to install a new ruby version on my M1 mac, in order to run a simple **bundle install** on a repo that was requiring a different ruby version than what I had. Ended up reinstalling brew and rbenv and ended up in the following situation.

If I run **brew install mysql** it succeeds.
Also **brew install openssl**.

When I run **bundle install** I gets stuck at the usual problematic point out there:

> Fetching mysql2 0.5.3
> Installing mysql2 0.5.3 with native extensions

I did run also succesfully

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

The error is:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

If I run **gcc -v** I get

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202).  
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0.   
Thread model: posix.  
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

And also before the error I have lots of warnings, amongst which:

```
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib'
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/lib/libzstd.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libcrypto.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
```

I am clearly missing what's going on..

UPDATE:

by running:

```
rbenv exec gem install mysql2 -- \
 --with-mysql-lib=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/lib \
 --with-mysql-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32 \
 --with-mysql-config=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/bin/mysql_config \
 --with-mysql-include=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/include
```

gives me still the same error but less warnings.. the only one left that I don't manage to solve is:

```
warning: ignoring file /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
```

don't know if I am on the right path tho..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue people experience on Apple Silicon Macs due to misunderstanding two main concepts:

### 1) arm64 vs x86_64

Apple Silicon Macs use the `arm64` architecture, which is not compatible with the `x86_64` architecture that would be used if you enable Rosetta, or run commands with `arch -x86_64`, or if you try to install gems or other tools that were built for the `x86_64` architecture.

You cannot mix and match architectures. For example, if you install Homebrew while using Rosetta or with `arch -x86_64`, it will install things under `/usr/local`. However, when installing Homebrew in native mode, it will be installed under `/opt/homebrew`.

If you have Homebrew installed in both locations, and you install `rbenv` or Ruby in native mode (arm64), you can't install a gem and tell it to look for stuff in `/usr/local` (x86_64). You either have to do everything in native mode with the `arm64` architecture, or do everything with the `x86_64` architecture, which I don't recommend at all.

To be sure you have a clean dev environment, I recommend completely removing all dev tools and starting over with a clean slate. But first, try updating the `mysql2` gem as explained in the second section below. If that doesn't fix things, then I would remove everything under both `/usr/local` and `/opt/homebrew`, as well as everything related to Ruby, then reinstall everything from scratch, while making sure you're not using Rosetta. You can check by running `uname -m` and `arch` in your terminal. They should both return `arm64`.

### 2) Using outdated gems that are not compatible with Apple Silicon

Another very common issue people run into on Apple Silicon Macs is not being able to install gems in existing projects that have old versions of gems. In your case, version 0.5.3 of `mysql2` was released on November 7, 2019, before the M1 Macs were released. You can check which gems are outdated by running `bundle outdated`, or look them up on rubygems.org. Here's the page for myslq2 that shows that latest version is 0.5.5 (which works on Apple Silicon): https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2

The first thing to check when a gem fails to install is to make sure it's up to date. Updating gems fixes 99% of issues.

So, in your case, once you have a proper Ruby development environment running in native mode, you can update the gem with `bundle update mysql2`. Then, if you run `bundle install` again and you get other installation failures, I would update those gems as well.

Comment: it does make sense and I thank you for the explanation! I removed everything under **usr/local/homebrew** in such a way to keep everything under the arm64 architecture.
I have a question if possible. When I add **eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"** to my .zshrc, it adds **/Users/<my-user>/.rbenv/shims** to PATH.. I guess that's alright? I would have expected something inside the **opt/homebrew** path but not.

Comment: Yes, that is alright and expected. That is where rbenv places its shims.